# yii2 Kartik-V Typeahead Basic autocomplete on name but store integer value

Tags: yii2, typeahead.js, yii-extensions

**Updates have been made below**

I am trying to use the Kartik-V Typeahead Basic widget with the Yii2 Framework.

The code below is working to display the required data, the user can search via the university name and it appears in the autocomplete list.

The issue is, the model needs to the university id, not the name. Thus the rules are this field can only store an integer and returns a validation error once you select one of the typeahead results.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'university_id')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(University::find()->all(),'id','uni_name'),
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
]); ?>
```

I am hoping someone can help me understand if there is a setting that needs to be changed so when saving, the user friendly 'uni_name' data is changed back to the uni 'id'.

**UPDATE:
I have gotten the code partly working thanks to "Insane Skull".**

The new code is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(University::find()->all(),'id','uni_name'),
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...', 'id' => 'testID'],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'typeahead:select' => new yii\web\JsExpression("function(event, ui) { $('#testing123').val(ui.item.id); }"),
    ]
]); ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'university_id', array ('id' => 'testing123'))?>
```

**Now I am unfortunately getting the error:**
Method yii\web\JsExpression::__toString() must return a string value

Comment: You better use this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather use [Select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) instead of Typeahead, you are basically trying to implement the functionality that already exists on Select2 but using Typeahead.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'university_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(University::find()->all(),'id','uni_name'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Marche,

I hadn't realised that Select2 has the ajax loading. my dataset will be large and I didn't want them all appearing straight away! This works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [activeHiddenInput()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeHiddenInput%28%29-detail) for this purpose.

Create one public variable in model say `name`.

Then:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(University::find()->all(),'id','uni_name'),
'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
'select' => new yii\web\JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                        $('#id_of_hiddenField').val(ui.item.id);
                    }")
]); ?>
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'university_id')?>
```

And in Controller Get the value of `activeHiddenField`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, unfortunately when I add this code, the page returns the error:
`Setting unknown property: kartik\typeahead\TypeaheadBasic::select`

Is there anything else that needs to be used differently?

The hidden field works, just not the newly included `select` statement

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I have progressed the code a little, you should be able to see the update above, do you have any knowledge of what is causing the new error?